Is there any built-in exception type for a boneheaded exception in .NET?
I have the following code in a shared component:
public class MyClass {

    public void DoWork() {

        // ...

        if (someConditionWhichShouldAlwaysBeFalse) {
            throw new Exception("If we get here, there must be a bug in MyClass.");
        }        
    }    
}

I'm wondering if there's an appropriate built-in exception type in .NET that indicates:

This exception is boneheaded, i.e. it must indicate a bug in my code
It is not caused by any illegal caller input. The caller is using MyClass perfectly legally, and the error is entirely caused by bugs within MyClass

In a way, I just want a stronger, exception-based version of Debug.Assert(). The purpose is entirely to catch bugs within my code and I expect callers not to catch the exception (except maybe for logging and rethrow).
Is there a built-in type in the framework that suits this purpose? I've seen people use InvalidOperationException sometimes but my understanding is that IOE should be used for caller input which is inconsistent with object state (i.e. it is still fundamentally a caller error).

"Rather, you should write your code so that the exception cannot possibly happen in the first place" - This is not an exception that should be implemented, it is just an exception type/classification based on code behavior. So when it appears ....for example a runtime wrong cast and your code is crashing.... now u have a "Boneheaded" exception.

@DA How about cases where I want to throw such a boneheaded exception, to indicate a bug in my code? For example in the middle of a computation algorithm, it should always be the case that a > b, otherwise it indicates a bug in my algorithm. I just want to add a check if (a <= b) throw new Exception(); to catch bugs. Is there an appropriate built-in exception type that I can use here?

There isn't such thing. Here u have a logic exception and you implement your own custom LogicException and throw it.

Don't throw exceptions to catch bugs, write tests instead.

I'd prefer Trace.Assert(!cond, message);

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682432/make-net-assertion-throw-an-exception-in-release-build

Sounds to me like UnreachableException is what you're looking for, introduced in .NET 7:

The exception that is thrown when the program executes an instruction that was thought to be unreachable


To the reviewers that voted to delete as link-only: the answer was 100% valid if the link rotted, even before my edit. The "link only" deletions should be used for answers that wouldn't make sense without the links.

Thanks! Exactly what I'm looking for!
